# Change Wordpress categories taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I Have multiple custom post types in admin, all post types have different categories,  but when i open any category tab all categories shows together. i want to do separate categories for every different post types

Comment: Is this when you view via the website itself or via admin? You'd need to share more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can register your custom category (taxonomy) for specific post type only.

like - food post type have - food category only. and car post type have car category only. follow below code.

```
// Register Custom category
function custom_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Taxonomies', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Taxonomy', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Taxonomy', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy', array( 'MYPOSTTYPE' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

in above for other you can change post type `MYPOSTTYPE` also changed name too

details 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies